# Set grid line to stay at a specific tick point in a variable Y-Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

In plotting a time series, the Y-Axis is defined as:

```
yAxis = np.arange(minY, maxY, stepY)
ax.set_ylim(minY, maxY)
ax.set_yticks(yAxis)
```

For visual reference, a dashline is added to highlight the 0% "Base" line per attached chart. To illustrate, this dashline is specified by [7] for this question:

```
yGrid = ax.get_ygridlines()
yBase = yGrid[7]
yBase.set_linestyle('--')
```

As the time series progresses, Y-Axis will change as minY and maxY limits are continually updated. How do I set the dashline to always stay at that specific 0% tick point given that range(minY, maxY) will not always be symmetrical about the 0% "Base" line?

[image: ASX-IndexASX-20170519]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, putting an additional line on top of the zero grid line is the easiest solution. This can be done using `ax.axhline(0)` as pointed out by tom.

The drawback may be that the gridline below the `axhline` is still present.

To answer to actual question: You may check which of the gridlines is the one at zero position and set the linestyle for that one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.arange(0,99)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(loc=0.1, size=len(x)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line, = ax.plot([],[], color="plum", lw=2)
ax.grid(color="lightgray", lw=2)

def update_gridline(pos):
    yGrid = ax.get_ygridlines()
    for i, gl in enumerate(yGrid):
        y  = gl.get_ydata()
        if y[0]==pos:
            gl.set_linestyle('--')
            gl.set_color('crimson')
        else:
            gl.set_linestyle('-')
            gl.set_color("lightgray")

def update(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    update_gridline(0)


ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=100, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Merci IOBE now that's one earnest to goodness response with animation! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying one of the gridlines, you could just plot another line at that point, using [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline), which will always then stay at the y location you give it:

```
ax.axhline(0, linestyle='--')
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom for a swift and direct solution!